# Ошибка при запуске .ехе файла в Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

[4824:1118/122145.102:ERROR:broker_win.cc(56)] Error reading broker pipe: ╩рэры с√ы чръЁ√Є. (0x6D)
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: На картинке есть только попытка запуска cpp файла

Comment: А это не ошибка VS Code? По-моему, к Вашей программе она никакого отношения не имеет. У Вас есть только main.cpp, который Вы почему-то пытаетесь запустить как исполняемый файл.